# how to return HashSet from a method?

Tags: java, return, return-value, hashset

I was struggling how to recall the data stored in an `HashMap` and `HashSet` and what would the method be to return the values stored in them and the size as well as the data?

```
public HashSet <Room>  getOccupiedrooms(){
    return occupiedRooms.size();
}
```

and this does not compile so I am not so sure.  and wound return the data stored.

cheers

Comment: _"and this dosent compile"_ Yes `size()` returns the number of elements in the set, not the set itself. A quick look at the doc would give you the answer of why this doesn't compile.

Comment: so how woudld i return the value stored within aswell

Comment: We don't know what's the data type of `occupiedRooms`, so we cannot answer, just do speculations.

Comment: @dave.2 try to look at my answer.

Comment: There isn't anywhere near enough information in this question for it to be useful.  In its current form, providing any sort of answer is impossible.  And the people who have provided some kind of answer all ought to be downvoted.  Voting to close.

Comment: its cause ive cant gte it to return unless it is changed from HashSet to int how can i get it to return the string values stored in the `Set

Comment: Well, you need to show us _at least_ the declaration of `occupiedRooms` before anyone can help you at all.

Comment: sorry the constructor is:   occupiedRooms = new HashSet<Room>();   the i store the data using this conditional statmen: public  void checkIn (String roomNo, String guest){
        if(validRoom(roomNo)){
            if (!roomTaken(roomNo)) {
                System.out.println(guest + " is booked in to room number: " + roomNo);
                occupiedRooms.add(new Room(roomNo, guest));

            }
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate on your hashset, Check every room if it's occupied and add the room to a diffferent HashSet.

```
public HashSet<Room>  getOccupiedrooms(){
HashSet<Room> tempSet = new HashSet<Room>();
// iterate start
// if room is occupied, add room to tempSet
// iterate end
// return tempSet
```

Answer (score 0):

lets assume that occupiedRooms is a HashSet. so just remove the .size();, in your code you are returning the size of your HashSet.

```
public HashSet <Room>  getOccupiedrooms(){
    return occupiedRooms;
}
```

so you can get its size by :

```
getOccupiedrooms().size();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to see what the difficulty is. Just return the `HashSet` itself:

```
return occupiedRooms;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are like me and didn't know it can't return within an if-statement, then that might be your problem. Just put the return statement outside your if-statement within your function.